# Compare email to a list

Tags: apex, trigger, formula

I need to run contacts or leads that have emails (insert or update) against the below list to determine if they are generic emails

The idea is to change a custom field Generic_Email__c to TRUE if they match the list

Problems:

1. I can't use formula field because the list is too big
2. Similarly, I try to create a List on trigger and I had the same issue

Your help is appreciated
AK

List is:

```
info@
sales@
office@
contact@
mail@
geral@
service@
enquiries@
verkauf@
accounts@
admin@
kontakt@
buchhaltung@
autohaus@
verwaltung@
poststelle@
geschaeftsleitung@
werkstatt@
infos@
auto@
fahrzeuge@
garage@
post@
comercial@
commercial@
marketing@
direction@
administracion@
reception@
accueil@
support@
webmaster@
kanzlei@
finance@
cars@
bodyshop@
email@
oficina@
kundendienst@
rechnung@
vertrieb@
technik@
ford@
hello@
enquires@
assurances@
shop@
accountspayable@
carrosserie@
bill@
purchaseledger@
nissan@
seat@
opel@
servis@
parts@
dispo@
gerencia@
carsales@
renault@
secretariat@
shaun@
kundenservice@
dp@
enquiry@
accounts.payable@
toyota@
wien@
team@
sekretariat@
zentrale@
vente@
ventas@
keine@
landrat@
enq@
gl@
citroen@
claims@
amministrazione@
repairs@
karosserie@
edv@
helpdesk@
it@
information@
holidays@
automobile@
vo@
postmaster@
salesmanager@
mitsubishi@
fleet@
honda@
anfrage@
redaction@
mazda@
fiat@
bookings@
contabilidad@
cabinet@
szerviz@
council@
administration@
compta@
aftersales@
club@
workshop@
peugeot@
recepcao@
presse@
firma@
redaktion@
reservations@
verkauf1@
purchase.ledger@
invoices@
hotline@
general@
customerservice@
bmw@
sale@
reservas@
verwaltung-p@
service.commercial@
usedcars@
transport@
services@
mailbox@
leasing@
eurotax@
direktion@
courrier@
contacto@
versicherung@
recht@
rechnungen@
noreply@
invoice@
dealer@
inf@
geschaeftsfuehrung@
informacion@
comptabilite@
assurance@
autoglas@
administrator@
spares@
poitiers@
tech@
staff@
```

Comment: You can add those list in some custom setting and write a Apex batch class for processing the records to check whether the Email falls into that list. For checking the Email you'll need to take a substring of that email and check against the list. If Yes mark the custom field to true else default will be false.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below piece of code in an Apex batch that check whether the Email falls in the given list category if yes then mark the custom field to True

```
//Create this Set from custom setting that you need to create and pull those value from the custom setting in to set below is just a sample set that i created
Set<String> emailSet = new Set<String>{'gmail.com'};
List<Contact> contactToUpdateList = new List<Contact>();
for(Contact obj: [Select Id,Email,Generic_Email__c from Contact Where Email != NULL]) {
    //Below condition will only check if the Email contains info, sales, office, contact if you want the @ as well then add that at the end of string before checking        if(emailSet.contains(String.valueOf(obj.Email).substringBefore('@'))){
        obj.Generic_Email__c = true;
        contactToUpdateList.add(obj);
    }
}
if(!contactToUpdateList.isEmpty()){
    update contactToUpdateList;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to go this route, but I am getting an error on the         if(myLead.Email.contains(email)){                                                          
 Trigger GenericEmailOnLead on Lead (before update, before insert) {
    
Set<String> email = new Set<String>();
email.add('info@');
email.add('sales@');
email.add('office@');
email.add('contact@');

    for(Lead myLead  : Trigger.new){
        if(myLead.Email.contains(email)){
               
        }
     }
}

Comment: You can't directly check `Email.contains` you'll need to take the substring as you're only checking the substr before @